# jQuery Validation plugin, Enable a checkbox when a field is valid

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery, jQuery Mobile and jQuery Validation plugin

I have a "password" field and a "rememberpassword" checkbox.

I would like the checkbox to be enabled only once the password field has been validated.

Here are the two fields in HTML

```
<input type="password" name="password" class="submit required" minlength="6" />
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberpassword" value="remember" />
```

To enable or disable the checkbox I use the jQuery Mobile commands

```
$('[name=rememberpassword]').checkboxradio( "enable" ); and
$('[name=rememberpassword]').checkboxradio( "disble" );
```

I can not figure out where I could add this commands in the validation rules.

I have tried to add the enable/disable commands in a validation rule for the password field as follow :

```
$(form).validate({
      rules: {
        password: {
          required: {
            depends: function(element) {
              console.log('In the password depends');
              if (!$(element).hasClass('error')) {
                $('[name=rememberpassword]').checkboxradio("enable");
              } else {
                $('[name=rememberpassword]').checkboxradio("disable");
              }
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Problem with this approach, the valid and error classes are added to the elements to validate only after the first data entry in the password field, so the checkbox remain valid.

I have also tried to validate the form or the password field with the `.valid()` method but this does not seem to do anything as long as the field has not been populated with something.

I tried to do the same thing but using the `.valid()` method on the password instead of testing for the presence of the error class, but this result rightly in a recursion until an error is returned.

I did not find a method to check for the validity of a field that would not trigger a full validation and the consequent recursion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show all attempts.  I am very interested to see how you tried it while using `.valid()`.

Comment: Hi Sparky, Sorry, I made so many attempts with all kind of contorted logic that I dont really remember what I attempted witht he .valid() function, Sorry ... :-(

Answer (score 2):

Conditional rules/functions are only meant for:

- when the rule depends on something else.  (Example: a field is only "required" when a checkbox is ticked.)

It's **not** meant for:

- running a function whenever a rule is satisfied on a field.

(*Yes, as you've seen, if you happen to use `.valid()` as part of a rule condition, you will cause recursion.*)

---

The solution is to use a `keyup` event handler function along with [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) to check the status of the field.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () { // <- DOM ready handler for jQuery Mobile

    // initialize plugin with .validate()
    $('#myform').validate({ 
        // your rules & options
    });

    // fire this function on every key-up event within the password field
    $('input[name="password"]').on('keyup', function () { 
        if ($(this).valid()) {             // <- check if password field is valid
            $('[name="rememberpassword"]')
                .checkboxradio('enable');  // <- enable checkbox
        } else {
            $('[name="rememberpassword"]')
                .checkboxradio('disable')  // <- disable checkbox
                .attr('checked',false)     // <- uncheck checkbox if checked
                .checkboxradio('refresh'); // <- refresh checkbox
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6eEBC/**

I chose not to make this part of the `onkeyup` callback function of the plugin since that would apply to every keyup event of *every field* on the form.

I also "uncheck" the checkbox because, I suppose, you don't want it stuck on "checked" if it goes disabled again.

According to [the jQuery Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/checkboxes/methods.html), you need to use `.checkboxradio('refresh')` when you "manipulate a checkbox via JavaScript" to update the visual styling.  As per the examples on that page, it only applies when you check/uncheck the checkbox programatically.

Comment: Hi Sparky, thanks, i was trying to stay strictly in the limits of the Validation plugin, while your solution work, it does break the rules set by the validation plugin, on initial data entry the plugin does a lazy validation, only displaying a message once the user exit the field, once the message displayed the plugin turn into strict validation and display keystroke by keystroke the error messages. While your solution function it can be irritating to have an error message appear immediately. The only solution I can think of is to replicate the validation rules in the `keyup` section. Thanks.

Comment: About the `.checkboxradio('refresh')` I found out that I do not need to use it when just enabling/disabling the checkbox.The refresh is needed when doing heavier  manipulations like for example dynamically adding a checkbox.

Comment: @Raymond, the "refresh" was only recommended as per the jQuery Mobile documentation and examples.  Just remove it if you don't think you need it.  As far as "breaking rules" set forth by the jQuery Validation plugin; this solution does no such thing.  However, you never described in your OP by which "events" were supposed trigger this enable/disable function.  Key-up seemed most logical so that's what I used.  Otherwise, what trigger would enable the checkbox?  Again, my solution is equally valid by just changing the event to `blur`.

Comment: Quote @Raymond: _"The only solution I can think of is to replicate the validation rules in the keyup section."_ ~ Then there's no point in using this plugin since it's not longer doing the validation.  Anyway, you asked about how this is done using this plugin, and I showed a concrete example that can be easily used with any trigger event.

Comment: Hi Sparky, Sorry, did not want to start an argument, I just pointed out what I think is a weakness of the solution you kindly offered, this site is about finding the best possible solution and discussing them openly. While your answer did not cover all my needs it did help me see the limits of what is possible with the plugin. I will use the plugin to validate other fields and use a home cooked solution for this specific requirement.

Comment: @Raymond, not an argument.  1.  This is me still trying to get you to explain how you want to trigger your code if not by the key-up event.  2.  Trying to comprehend how a mash-up of the plugin with some custom validation is _"the best possible"_ as compared to my very straightforward solution using only the plugin for validation.

Comment: @Raymond, What do you think the `.valid()` method was created for anyway? ~ Answer:  it's for programatically checking validity... and doing that only outside of the scope of the `.validate()` call.  In other words, `.valid()` gives the programmer a method to "test" a field or form _from within his own code_.  So, IMO, this is the _best possible solution_ since it uses every part of the plugin exactly as intended without having to write separate validation code for one field by itself.

Comment: Hi Sparky, Triggering Code : The idea is to use the plugin to avoid having to do the validation myself and not think about the event I want to use and keep it simple. I am not sure how the plugin operate internally, but I like the way it does an initial lazy validation with no initial message displayed and then go to strict validation once you leave the field, that's what I would like to replicate.

Comment: .validate() was created to validate, I got that, if it could be used silently, aka, without generating the error messages it would be great as I could test validity for example on keyup without displaying the error message when in the initial lazy validation phase.

Comment: @Raymond, then simply change the triggering event to blur for enabling the checkbox.  The plugin code is still operating by all its defaults.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/6eEBC/1/

Comment: @Raymond, Please re-read that comment more carefully.  The `.valid()` method is not the same as the `.validate()` method.

Comment: @Raymond, `.validate()` was created to intialize the plugin. `.valid()` was created so you can programmatically check validation status. Two different things. My point was that my answer is using the plugin and its methods exactly as designed.  And here it is with `keyup` validation disabled: http://jsfiddle.net/6eEBC/2/